# Disable encryption on storage card without hard reset

Tags: c#, windows-mobile

I am using windows mobile 6.1 and attempting to disable the encryption on the Storage Card without resetting device. It appears if the storage card is encrypted that i can go into the ctlpnl and uncheck it and click ok which does what i want and decrypts right then. If I change it by the registry key it won't decrypt until i reboot the device.How can I decrypt it without rebooting like it does in the ctlpnl?

How can i tell what happens when the Ok button is clicked?

So far I can get the checkbox to update by doing the below code. But It does not still decrypt the storage card.

thanks

```
[DllImport("coredll.dll")]
public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint msg, int wParam, int lParam);
[DllImport("coredll.dll")]
public static extern bool SendMessageTimeout(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, int wParam, int lParam, int fuFlags, int uTimeout, out int lpdwResult);
[DllImport("coredll.dll")]
public static extern bool PostMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, int wParam, int lParam);

public const int HWND_BROADCAST = 0xffff;
public const int WM_WININICHANGE = 0x1A;
public const int WM_SETTINGCHANGE = 0x1A;
public const int SMTO_NORMAL = 0x0000; 
public const int SMTO_BLOCK = 0x0001;

 SendMessage((IntPtr)HWND_BROADCAST, WM_WININICHANGE, 0, 0);
            SendMessage((IntPtr)HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SETTINGCHANGE, 0, 0);
            PostMessage((IntPtr)HWND_BROADCAST, WM_WININICHANGE, 0, 5000);
            PostMessage((IntPtr)HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SETTINGCHANGE, 0, 5000);
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in my comment, you can use wap provisioning: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb416357.aspx

```
<wap-provisioningdoc>
    <characteristic type="SecurityPolicy">     <!-- Set encryption policy such that the user cannot change the setting -->
        <parm name="4134" value="0" /> 
    </characteristic>
    <characteristic type="MobileEncryption">   <!-- Turn on encryption -->
        <parm name="Enable" value="1" /> 
    </characteristic>
</wap-provisioningdoc>
```

Changes will only apply to files stored on sd card AFTER the change. So encrypted files remain encrypted until you copy them.

Comment: user has posted a comment, Josef, but he posted it under my answer.

Answer (score 0):

That is what encryption is for. It is not designed to be easy to get around.

Either you will have to find a way to break the encryption (i.e. contact the vendor about removing their encryption) or you will need to take what you want off of the SD card and re-format it.

Comment: I am not trying to break the encryption. I have the key on the device and really am just trying to figure out away to do the same thing as when the ok button it pressed. I can reformat the card all I want but if encryption is still enabled it will re encrypt until device it rebooted.

Comment: Lets just say i am fine with formatting and also changed the encryptmydefault = 0. How can i tell windows mobile to stop encrypting future files copied to the device without a reboot?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. It sounds like something a manufacturer added, since Windows does not encrypt SD cards (not in older Windows Mobile, anyway). It sounds like you will need to contact this manufacturer or find an SDK for it off of their website.

Comment: Well Windows Mobile 61 does encryption for sure. This is info on it.
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsmobile/archive/2007/03/26/windows-mobile-6-storage-card-encryption-faq.aspx
it appears that i can't even call the control panel applet and make it click ok due to that applet being locked.

Comment: Yes, Windows Mobile 6 supports SD Card Encryption by default.See also my issue with SD Card having the EncFiltLog.menc file on it (http://www.hjgode.de/wp/2009/06/15/windows-mobile-memory-card-encryption-stops-winxp-from-reading-the-card/). This file is a marker set by WM6.x.

Comment: if i set that wap provisioning to disable would i have to reboot the device before it takes effect? Well about to try.